# push object inside object in while loop

Tags: javascript

```js
let num = 6;
if (num < 13 && num > 1) {
  let base = 1;
  let remaining = num - 1;
  let result = {
    l: num,
    r: remaining
  };
  while (remaining <= 12 && remaining >= 1) {
    let o = {
      l: num,
      r: remaining
    }
    result["r"] = o;
    console.log(result, o);
    remaining--
  }
  console.log(result)
  //return result;
} else {
  throw new Error('Invalid number');
}
```

I want to loop 6 times and in result, the r key of result must have object inside object. number should be greater that 12 or less than 1, and want to push o inside the r 6 times.
I tried object accessing like object.key or object[key] but now confused

output i want like

```
{l:num,r:{l:num,r{...so on 6 times}}}
```

Comment: you need to reassign `result` on each loop otherwise you're just overwriting

Comment: What is the purpose of `r: remaining` when you overwrite that property immediately afterwards? Can you show the *complete* desired result? What does the innermost object look like? Does it have an `r` property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `result` object always gets the same `r` property overwritten. Instead you would want to have an object reference to the new object that was assigned to that `r` property, so that in the next iteration the `r` property of that nested object is expanded, and not the top-level one.

Two changes are needed -- see comments:

```js
let num = 6;
if (num < 13 && num > 1) {
  let base = 1;
  let remaining = num - 1;
  let result = {
    l: num,
    r: remaining
  };
  let r = result; // Keep track of the innermost object  
  while (remaining <= 12 && remaining >= 1) {
    let o = {
      l: num,
      r: remaining
    }
    r = r.r = o; // r should "follow" the newly created object
    remaining--
  }
  console.log(result)
} else {
  throw new Error('Invalid number');
}
```

Note that `r: remaining` in the object literal creates a property that in the next iteration gets overwritten by the statement `r.r = o`, so only for the very last created object is that `remaining` a useful value to assign (always 1).

This job can be accomplished in a more elegant way by creating the objects from the inside out, each time wrapping a new object around the earlier created object. `reduce` is a handy method for this:

```js
const createNested = l =>
    Array.from({length: l}).reduce(r => ({ l, r }), 1);

console.log(createNested(6));
```

This can also be done with an explicit loop:

```js
const createNested = l => {
    let r = 1;
    for (let i = 0; i < l; i++) r = { l, r };
    return r; 
}
console.log(createNested(6));
```

Comment: thanks, literally was very confusing. I want to achieve that in while loop because I read somewhere that its is 60% faster than reduce and other method.